# MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI return an empty cursor

Tags: android, mediastore

In android I can't figure out why this cursor is empty in htc wildfire. but works on all other phones
there are several audiofiles on the sdcard.
the stock mediaplayer can find and play these songs alright.

```
Cursor c = managedQuery(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, new String[] { "distinct " + MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM, MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_KEY, MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID}, 
                null,
                null, 
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
```

If there is anyone out there that has been able to successfully query the mediastore.audio.media on a wildfire, please let me know.

Update: Apperantly it's just on this single device. Other wildfire's work fine. Still it seems strange that both the ambling book player (I'm guessing they just loop through the folders and do their own id3 parsing) and the stock android music player find the music but I can't get anything from the mediastore. No ".nomedia" files are present, I have tried inserting new mp3 files to a new folder.

Is there no one out there that has experienced this behaviour with, not necessarily a wildfire, just any android device.

Comment: I see the same problem on Nexus 7. The same code works fine on Samsung Galaxy Tab but not on Nexus 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4972968/empty-cursor-from-the-mediastore)

Answer (score 0):

HTC is known for screwing with the Intent patterns.  Google hasn't locked down the requirements given in the [Compatibility Document](http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/source.android.com/en/us/compatibility/android-2.3-cdd.pdf) for all types. My guess is that is what is going on here.  You'll need to find what HTC changed the MediaStore Intent patterns to and implement a fix for it.

Comment: Well it does work on the htc desire. So I'm not sure if that's the problem ...but maybe.