# android listview adapter cursor

Tags: android, cursor, android-listview, adapter

```
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.artistname);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
    String val = extras.getString("artistname");

    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), val, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    String result = null;
    InputStream is = null;
    StringBuilder sb = null;

    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

    try{

    //http post
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    //HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.0.5/staging/android/get_search_result.php?keyword=Chinna_Mani&format=json");
```

HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.0.5/staging/android/get_search_result.php?keyword="+val+"&format=json&flg=1");

```
    //HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.0.5/staging/android/ilaiyarajawebservice.php?format=xml");
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    is = entity.getContent();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),e.toString() ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }

    //Convert response to string  
    try
    {
      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"UTF-8"));

      sb = new StringBuilder();

      String line = null;

      while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
      {
         sb.append(line + "\n");
      }

      is.close();

      result = sb.toString();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),e.toString() ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    //END Convert response to string   
    try{
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            JSONObject json_data=null;
            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++)
            {
               json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);


               r.add(json_data.getString("artistfirstname"));


              // r.add(json_data.getString("file_name")+json_data.getString("artist_name") +json_data.getString("album_name"));

            }                                              
        }                            



    catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

            finally {      



        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);



         if(null != cursor)
        {

                 cursor.moveToFirst();

                setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.custom_list_item, r));

             }
             else{
```

//i want like this i develope alert message here playlist not found

```
                 System.out.println("playlist not  found");

        }
        }
            }
```

I need help on if the value `r` having content then display, if not have content then I want to set alert "no list found" how can I achieve that? i have try using else but not success.

Comment: i posted my full source, its not working please give solution

Answer (score 1):

```
if(null != cursor && cursor.getCount()>0 )//check cursor is not null and having atleast 1 data
 {
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.custom_list_item, r));        

    //do your operation with content
 }
else
  //show alert here i.e. no list found
```

Comment: not came else part execute if only

Comment: Check your database/cursor, whether they having record or not?

Comment: i post full source please find and give solution

Answer (score 0):

```
if(null != cursor)
{
    //other work......

    if (cursor.getCount () > 0 )
    {        
         //show alert 

    } 
    else
    {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.custom_list_item, r));
    }
```

Comment: Hello, I would like to comment the same here which I did on ViputShah's Answer..You to please check that and Keep Up the Good Work..!

Comment: Thanks MKJParekh I will keep in mind that for future ... but  I think this question was very simple that's why i did not found any thing extra to write :)

Comment: Yeh that happens many times that we try to answer simple question simply just by a short and sweet solution, All understand it. (but remember for the Questioner the thing is been hard then only he has asked question )

Comment: i try but not working only if condition only execute. i don't know i think any changes in web service?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4972968/empty-cursor-from-the-mediastore

Comment: i posted my full source, its not working please give solution

Comment: so it mean cursor is null every time as if going to else always .........

Comment: no always if executing, content is display or not always if execute how?

Comment: may be cursor is empty for that query.......

Comment: or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4972968/empty-cursor-from-the-mediastore

Answer (score 0):

You just need to check the Cursor for that, If cursor has atleast one data then try to move to the first record, as `cursor.moveToFirst()` returns `boolean` value if have first record then True else False, you can use that directly to check if the Cursor have fetched data or not as below.

```
if(cursor.moveToFirst())
{
   //Populate Contents
}
else
{
  //No Contents Found
}
```

Comment: Hello, I have been marking that you have been really very well active in Android Tag and answering so frequently and that's very nice, Thanks and Congrates to you, I want to suggest you to try giving solutions with explainations cause your answer with correct sol are manytime shown in Review as Low Quality so please improve that also :) Keep Doing The Great Work.!!

Comment: i posted my full source, its not working please give solution

Answer (score 0):

```
if(r.size()>0){    
 Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

     if(null != cursor)
     {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.custom_list_item, r));        
//here I need help the value are having content means display, if not have content means I want set alert no list found how? I will try else but not success.



   }
}else{
```

you can show Alert her by creating dialog and tell user that list is empty for creating dialog you can refer [best Link..](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidDialogs/article.html)

```
   }
```

just added checking for arraylist contains elements or not if not then you can display alert through Toast or dialog as i provided link for it.
--------------------------Here is your problems solution-------------------------------------------

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.artistname);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
    String val = extras.getString("artistname");

    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), val, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    String result = null;
    InputStream is = null;
    StringBuilder sb = null;

    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

    try{

    //http post
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    //HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.0.5/staging/android/get_search_result.php?keyword=Chinna_Mani&format=json");
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.0.5/staging/android/get_search_result.php?keyword="+val+"&format=json&flg=1");

    //HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.0.5/staging/android/ilaiyarajawebservice.php?format=xml");
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    is = entity.getContent();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),e.toString() ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }

    //Convert response to string  
    try
    {
      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"UTF-8"));

      sb = new StringBuilder();

      String line = null;

      while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
      {
         sb.append(line + "\n");
      }

      is.close();

      result = sb.toString();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),e.toString() ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    //END Convert response to string   
    try{
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            JSONObject json_data=null;
            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++)
            {
               json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);


               r.add(json_data.getString("artistfirstname"));


              // r.add(json_data.getString("file_name")+json_data.getString("artist_name") +json_data.getString("album_name"));

            }                                              
        }                            



    catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

            finally {      

if(r.size()>0){

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);



         if(null != cursor)
        {

                 cursor.moveToFirst();

                setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.custom_list_item, r));

             }
}else{

Toast.makeToast(getApplicationcontext(),"no Records ...", Toast.SHORT).show();

        }

        }
            }
```

Hope this explanation works for you.. appreciate

Comment: i try but not working only if condition only execute. i don't know i think any changes in web service?

Comment: i posted my full source, its not working please give solution

Comment: what is r and where it's define in your code..??

Comment: answer is edited have a look just check size of ArrayList

Comment: I didn't get you which code? 
Rather just make some changes to your code it will work fine as i suggested..

Comment: ya that wat i am saying pls modify and update