# How to check android applications public intents

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to create application for controlling my "Google Music" (com.google.android.music).
How can I find all acceptable intents?

Actually it's one side of my question. I am interested in some common method to find public intent in applications.

Is it possible with script? Something like: find installed applications `.apk`, extract **manifest**, **check public intents-filter**?

Answer (score 0):

To check installed applications on android device use following code

```
   Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
   myIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
   List installedApps = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities( myIntent, 0);
```

For google play question [THIS SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15110795/what-does-the-id-field-in-an-android-google-play-music-broadcast-intent-corr) post might be useful